# how to copy/cut text from vim to system clipboard use line number

Tags: vim

Be just like title，I know how to copy/cut to system clipboard `"+yy`,and it works! But my question is how can I use line number copy/cut section text,such as use `:1,10y` to yank 1 to 10 lines,can I use the same way to copy/cut to system clipboard,if can not ? Is there a simliar way for the same purpose ? （Actually，I have try to `:1,10"+yy`,but did not worked !）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the `"{reg}` prefix for normal mode, to indicate that you want to specify a register. For Ex commands, you just append the register name.

```
:1,10yank +
```

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor. `:help :yank` explains this:

> ```
> :[range]y[ank] [x]       Yank [range] lines [into register x]. Yanking to the
>                         "* or "+ registers is possible only when the
>                         |+clipboard| feature is included.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for solved my problem.:) As you said vim is a powerful editor.Every so offen there will be a surprise in my way of learning vim

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark on its left.